# Consultar y añadir nuevos valores a un diccionario de listas

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

estoy intentando consultar y añadir valores en un diccionario de listas utilizando defaultdict() y append().

Mi diccionario debería ser así pero no consigo que se creen las listas dentro:

```
  "key1": {
    "id": [123,456,789]
    "name": ["Pepe","Maria","Juan"]
  },
  "key2": {
    "id": [987,654,321]
    "name": ["Carlos","Laura","Pepe"]
  },
```

Y este es mi código:

```
usuarios = defaultdict(list)

for keys in usuarios:                           
    if usuarios[key]['id'] != user_id           
        print(" Usuario nuevo con id",user_id)  
        usuarios[key]['id'].append(user_id)
        usuarios[key]['name'].append(name)     
    else:
        print(" Ya está en la lista, no se añade")
```

El error que obtengo es: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' y según tengo entendido append solo funciona en listas que es lo que estoy intentando hacer.

Buscando por internet decían que la solución al error anterior era añadir los nuevos valores de esta forma:

```
usuarios[key]['id'] = usuarios[key]['id'] + chat_id
usuarios[key]['name'] = usuarios[key]['name'] + name
```

Pero tampoco me ha funcionado, el error ha sido: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Por último también he intentado obtener y añadir valores recorriendo el diccionario con un índice (`usuarios[key]['id'][i]`), pero nada...

Muchas gracias, a ver si me podéis arrojar algo de luz!

Comment: eso se debe a que muy seguramente `usuarios[key]['id']` es un entero y para usar append debe de ser una lista

Comment: Eso no es un diccionario de listas: es un diccionario de diccionarios, cada uno de los cuales contiene listas.

Comment: `usuarios[key]['id']` es una lista. No puedes comparar una lista contra un entero como haces en el `if`.

Comment: Tu estructura está mal diseñada. Si estás manejando usuarios, la clave debería ser el `id` del usuario. ¿Cual es la lógica de tu problema?

Comment: Me ha dado más de 3 problemas de sintaxis, podrías poner el código de tal forma de que sea replicable? Es un problema adicional innecesario. 1) el diccionario no está bien definido. 2) en el `for` tienes `keys` pero en el cuerpo usas `key`. 3) `user_id` y otras variables no definidas... 4) defaultdict no definido

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres manejar y validar usuarios, la estructura correcta es un diccionario cuya clave sea el `user_id` y cuyo valor sea el nombre.

Definimos una función `agregar` que sólo agrega al diccionario cuando el `user_id` es nuevo. Si ya existe, no hace nada.

```
def agregar(diccionario, user_id, nombre):
    if user_id in diccionario:
        return False
    diccionario[user_id] = nombre
    return True
```

Como la llave es el `user_id`, me basta preguntar `if user_id in diccionario` para validar el usuario.

#### Demo

```
def agregar(diccionario, user_id, nombre):
    if user_id in diccionario:
        return False
    diccionario[user_id] = nombre
    return True

nuevos = [
    (1, "Juan"),
    (2, "Maria"),
    (3, "Jose"),
    (1, "Alberto"),
]

diccionario = {}

for user_id, nombre in nuevos:
    print("Agregar", user_id, nombre, end=": ")
    if agregar(diccionario, user_id, nombre):
        print("Agregado")
    else:
        print("Duplicado")

print(diccionario)
```

produce:

```
Agregar 1 Juan: Agregado
Agregar 2 Maria: Agregado
Agregar 3 Jose: Agregado
Agregar 1 Alberto: Duplicado
{1: 'Juan', 2: 'Maria', 3: 'Jose'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```